# Visual Studio problem with git commit and csprj files

Tags: git, visual-studio-2019

I have an issue in some Visual Studio C# projects, when I commit changes in a c# project. If I added a new file to the project, this information is added to the csprj-file of the project.
I do a git commit and the change of the csprj-file is in this commit, but in the csprj-file is still listed list of not committed changes in git.
I must do a second commit to commit the csprj-file. 
The csprj-file is included in both commits and has the same content.
I have the same behavior, if i do the commits with git client like TortoiseGit instead of using the Team Explorer in Visual Studio.

What could I do to repair this?
I use Visual Studio 2019 Version 16.4.3

Comment: `.csproj` files are usually kept out of the scope of version control. There's usually no value to diffing them since they're generated from versioned sources files already. Did you consider using `.gitignore` for that? Did you reject this for some reason unknown to us?

Comment: Is this really true? If you do not have a csproj-file in an Visual Studio project like an asp.net mvc project, the project will not load. So you need the file in version control for the other developers.

Comment: To be clearer, you're right, in some contexts it makes sense. I was alluding to the fact that *build objects* are usually kept out of version control, but it might have been a mischaracterization of my part for `.csproj` files, I'm sorry for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for your help.

I looked at the problem with a colleague again and we found the cause for the problem.
A few month ago, I renamed the namespace and the project name from "xxx.**ICS**.Datalayer" to "xxx.**Ics**.Datalayer".

After this in my visual studio solution on my Windows computer I had one project file: "xxx.Ics.Datalayer.csproj", but today we realized that in the git-repository we have two files "xxx.Ics.Datalayer.csproj" and ""xxx.ICS.Datalayer.csproj". 
I did not recognize that the first commit was for the change with the old filename and the second commit was for the new filename.

To fix the problem, I saved the csproj file and then deleted it. The commit with the deletion then deleted both files in the git repository. Afterwards I could insert the csproj file into the Visual Studio Solution again.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able, before your first commit, to add the modified csproj as well.
(Typically, right-click + stage, as [in this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/commits?view=azure-devops&tabs=visual-studio#stage-your-changes))

That way, *one* commit is enough to be record the new file *and* the modified `.csproj` project file.